# What is original Persian text of Rumi for the following English translation?

Tags: persian-language, rumi

> Dance, when you're broken open.
>   Dance, if you've torn the bandage off.
>   Dance in the middle of the fighting.
>   Dance in your blood.
>   Dance when you're perfectly free.

Comment: Found it: رقص آنجا کن کہ خود را بشکنی
پنبہ را از ریش شہوت بر کنی
رقص و جولاں برسر میداں کنند
رقص اندر خون خود مرداں کنند
چوں رہند از دست خود دستے زنند
چوں جہند از نقص بر رقصے تنند

مثنوی مولانا روم۔ جلد سوم

Comment: You can post that as an answer, along with the name of the poem

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are doing well.
This is full text of this poem from the book three of Masnavi

> آن شنیدی تو که در هندوستان
>
> دید دانایی گروهی دوستان
>
> گرسنه مانده شده بی‌برگ و عور
>
> می‌رسیدند از سفر از راه دور
>
> مهر داناییش جوشید و بگفت
>
> خوش سلامیشان و چون گلبن شکفت
>
> گفت دانم کز تجوع وز خلا
>
> جمع آمد رنجتان زین کربلا
>
> لیک الله الله ای قوم جلیل
>
> تا نباشد خوردتان فرزند پیل
>
> پیل هست این سو که اکنون می‌روید
>
> پیل‌زاده مشکرید و بشنوید
>
> پیل‌بچگانند اندر راهتان
>
> صید ایشان هست بس دلخواهتان
>
> بس ضعیف‌اند و لطیف و بس سمین
>
> لیک مادر هست طالب در کمین
>
> از پی فرزند صد فرسنگ راه
>
> او بگردد در حنین و آه آه
>
> آتش و دود آید از خرطوم او
>
> الحذر زان کودک مرحوم او
>
> اولیا اطفال حق‌اند ای پسر
>
> غایبی و حاضری بس با خبر
>
> غایبی مندیش از نقصانشان
>
> کو کشد کین از برای جانشان
>
> گفت اطفال من‌اند این اولیا
>
> در غریبی فرد از کار و کیا
>
> از برای امتحان خوار و یتیم
>
> لیک اندر سر منم یار و ندیم
>
> پشت‌دار جمله عصمتهای من
>
> گوییا هستند خود اجزای من
>
> هان و هان این دلق‌پوشان من‌اند
>
> صد هزار اندر هزار و یک تن‌اند
>
> ورنه کی کردی به یک چوبی هنر
>
> موسیی فرعون را زیر و زبر
>
> ورنه کی کردی به یک نفرین بد
>
> نوح شرق و غرب را غرقاب خود
>
> بر نکندی یک دعای لوط راد
>
> جمله شهرستانشان را بی مراد
>
> گشت شهرستان چون فردوسشان
>
> دجلهٔ آب سیه رو بین نشان
>
> سوی شامست این نشان و این خبر
>
> در ره قدسش ببینی در گذر
>
> صد هزاران ز انبیای حق‌پرست
>
> خود بهر قرنی سیاستها بدست
>
> گر بگویم وین بیان افزون شود
>
> خود جگر چه بود که کهها خون شود
>
> خون شود کهها و باز آن بفسرد
>
> تو نبینی خون شدن کوری و رد
>
> طرفه کوری دوربین تیزچشم
>
> لیک از اشتر نبیند غیر پشم
>
> مو بمو بیند ز صرفه حرص انس
>
> رقص بی مقصود دارد همچو خرس
>
> `رقص آنجا کن که خود را بشکنی`
>
> `پنبه را از ریش شهوت بر کنی`
>
> `رقص و جولان بر سر میدان کنند`
>
> `رقص اندر خون خود مردان کنند`
>
> `چون رهند از دست خود دستی زنند`
>
> `چون جهند از نقص خود رقصی کنند`
>
> مطربانشان از درون دف می‌زنند
>
> بحرها در شورشان کف می‌زنند
>
> تو نبینی لیک بهر گوششان
>
> برگها بر شاخها هم کف‌زنان
>
> تو نبینی برگها را کف زدن
>
> گوش دل باید نه این گوش بدن
>
> گوش سر بر بند از هزل و دروغ
>
> تا ببینی شهر جان با فروغ
>
> سر کشد گوش محمد در سخن
>
> کش بگوید در نبی حق هو اذن
>
> سر به سر گوشست و چشم است این نبی
>
> تازه زو ما مرضعست او ما صبی
>
> این سخن پایان ندارد باز ران
>
> سوی اهل پیل و بر آغاز ران

Comment: Welcome to Literature SE! Would it be possible to include an English translation of this poem, either your own or an accurate one from elsewhere? Just because there's so many bad Rumi translations out there, it would be good for us non-Farsi-speakers to know what the poem really says.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yes, it needs a lot of attention to translate Rumi's poetry. Molana's poetry consists of many layers, and their decoding and translation require not only proficiency in English language but also in-depth knowledge of his poetry. Certainly, if I can do that, I will not hesitate. However, I am trying to find a transliteration of this poem and give it to you.